# Why are the particles floating around the objects instead of sticking to it?

Tags: particles

[image: The Picture]
So I am trying to add some sprinkles to the Donut as I have been revising myself of a tutorial from Blender Guru. It worked fine, but then my computer crashed and I didn't have a chance to save it. I am very new to blender, and I have researched some from here but they didn't work this out. So, I am wondering what is causing such problem.

Answer (score 2):

The emitted particles (sprinkles) are attached to the emitter (donut) in their origin points. If the origin point is far from the object, the emitted particle will be far from its emitter. Check the origin point of the emitted object, Perhaps it's not adjusted to geometry.

Select the emitted object (the sprinkle) > Right click > Set origin > Origin to geometry.

Answer (score 1):

edit mode (the single object that you use as RENDER object of the emitter), move and rotate till the emissions are ok.